# SUM window function with complications for date ranges Oracle PL/SQL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to determine the balance of a forecast minus orders, but with some wiggle room on the dates.   A forecast for 2/9/20 could be matched against an order shipping anywhere from 2/2/20 to 3/1/20 because of this wiggle room.  Similarly, an order shipping on 2/16/20 could count against a forecast anywhere from 2/9/2020 to 3/8/2020. I have been attempting to write this using a sum over partition by window function, but I'm getting thrown by the date range part.  It's pretty easy to get a running balance of forecast minus orders over time, but not when the sum ranges start and stop all over the place.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLEDATA
(
  DMDUNIT          VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  DMDGROUP         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  LOC              VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  EVENT_DATE        DATE,
  VALID_FROM       DATE,
  VALID_TO         DATE,
  FCSTID           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  QTY              NUMBER,
  RANKER           NUMBER,
  BALANCE_DESIRED  NUMBER
);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('02/09/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('02/02/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',8,1,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('02/16/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('02/09/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/08/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'ORDER',-20,0,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('02/16/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('02/09/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/08/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',8,1,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('02/23/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('02/16/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'ORDER',-40,0,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('02/23/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('02/16/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',13,1,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('02/23/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('02/16/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',37,2,6);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('03/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('02/23/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/22/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',24,1,24);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('03/08/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/01/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/29/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',7,1,7);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('03/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/08/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('04/05/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',8,1,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('03/22/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('04/12/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'ORDER',-15,0,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('03/22/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/15/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('04/12/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',5,1,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('03/29/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/22/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('04/19/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',9,1,7);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('04/05/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('03/29/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('04/26/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',7,1,7);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('04/12/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('04/05/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',7,1,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('04/19/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('04/12/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/10/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'ORDER',-50,0,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('04/19/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('04/12/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/10/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',7,1,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('04/26/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('04/19/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/17/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',7,1,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('05/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('04/26/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'ORDER',-14,0,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('05/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('04/26/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',7,1,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('05/10/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/03/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/31/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',23,1,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('05/17/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/10/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('06/07/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',7,1,0);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('05/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/17/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('06/14/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',9,1,2);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('05/31/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/24/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('06/21/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',8,1,8);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('06/07/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('05/31/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('06/28/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',16,1,16);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('06/14/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('06/07/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('07/05/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',6,1,6);
INSERT INTO SAMPLEDATA (DMDUNIT,DMDGROUP,LOC,EVENT_DATE,VALID_FROM,VALID_TO,FCSTID,QTY,RANKER,BALANCE_DESIRED) VALUES ('ITEM_A','CUSTOMER_B','LOCATION_C',to_date('06/21/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('06/14/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),to_date('07/12/2020','MM/DD/YYYY'),'FORECAST',16,1,16);


select sd.*  from sampledata sd order by 1,2,3,4,8;
```

The column labeled "Balance_Desired" is what the results of the sum over window function should be.  For example, the -20 order on line 2 covered all the forecast on line 1, line 3, and partially (4 units) of line 5.  The order for 40 on line 4 covered the remaining 9 on line 5 and all but size units of line 6.

So how do you set a sliding window in a sum over partition by that doesn't end up counting the same order against multiple forecasts?

Thanks for your thoughts,

John